# passing over conten of union between lex and yacc

Tags: c, bison, flex-lexer, yacc, lex

Simply I made a union in my yacc file that is:

```
%union { char* x; int y;}
```

in my lex file, I have something like:

```
"+"     {yylval.x = yytext; yylval.y=1}
```

but the contents aren't being copied when I print them in yacc

```
rule:  rules  {printf("%s %d", yylval.x, yylval.1);}
```

how do I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

yytext is available until it is in scope of scan but later its value is undefined.
Simple solution is to strdup() yytext in scanner and use its stored value in bison and
also making sure to free that memory. Below can be workable.

```
"+"     {yylval.x = strdup(yytext); yylval.y=1}
```